# How to put BG96 on power save mode between sending messages to Azure IoT Hub over HTTP

Tags: embedded, azure-iot-hub, mbed, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using a Nucleo L496ZG, X-NUCLEO-IKS01A2 and the Quectel BG96 module to send sensor data (temperature, humidity etc..) to Azure IoT Central over HTTP. 
I've been using the example implementation provided by Avnet [here](https://github.com/Avnet/azure-iot-mbed-client), which works fine but it's not power optimized and with a 6700mAh battery pack it only lasts around 30 hours sending telemetry ever ~10 seconds. Goal is for it to last around a week. I'm open to increasing the time between messages but I also want to save power in between sending.

I've gone over the Quectel BG96 manuals and I've tried two things:

1) powering off the device by driving the PWRKEY and turning it back on when I need to send a message 
I've gotten this to work, kinda… until I get a hardfault exception which happens seemingly randomly anywhere from within ~5 minutes of running to 2 hours (messages successfully sending prior to the exception). Output of crash log parser is the same every time:

```
        Crash location = strncmp [0x08038DF8] (based on PC value)
        Caller location = _findenv_r [0x0804119D] (based on LR value)
        Stack Pointer at the time of crash = [20008128]
        Target and Fault Info:
                Processor Arch: ARM-V7M or above
                Processor Variant: C24
                Forced exception, a fault with configurable priority has been escalated to HardFault
                A precise data access error has occurred. Faulting address: 03060B30
```

The caller location traces back to my .map file and I don't know what to make of it.
My code:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

//#define USE_MQTT

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mbed.h"
#include "iothubtransporthttp.h"
#include "iothub_client_core_common.h"
#include "iothub_client_ll.h"
#include "azure_c_shared_utility/platform.h"
#include "azure_c_shared_utility/agenttime.h"
#include "jsondecoder.h"
#include "bg96gps.hpp"
#include "azure_message_helper.h"

#define IOT_AGENT_OK CODEFIRST_OK

#include "azure_certs.h"


/* initialize the expansion board && sensors */

#include "XNucleoIKS01A2.h"
static HTS221Sensor   *hum_temp;
static LSM6DSLSensor  *acc_gyro;
static LPS22HBSensor  *pressure;


static const char* connectionString = "xxx";

// to report F uncomment this #define CTOF(x)         (((double)(x)*9/5)+32)
#define CTOF(x)         (x)

Thread azure_client_thread(osPriorityNormal, 10*1024, NULL, "azure_client_thread");
static void azure_task(void);
EventFlags deleteOK;
size_t g_message_count_send_confirmations;

/* create the GPS elements for example program */
BG96Interface* bg96Interface;

//static int tilt_event;

// void mems_int1(void)
// {
//     tilt_event++;
// }

void mems_init(void)
{
    //acc_gyro->attach_int1_irq(&mems_int1);  // Attach callback to LSM6DSL INT1
    hum_temp->enable();                     // Enable HTS221 enviromental sensor
    pressure->enable();                     // Enable barametric pressure sensor
    acc_gyro->enable_x();                   // Enable LSM6DSL accelerometer
    //acc_gyro->enable_tilt_detection();      // Enable Tilt Detection

}

void powerUp(void) {
        if (platform_init() != 0) {
            printf("Error initializing the platform\r\n");
            return;
        }
        bg96Interface = (BG96Interface*) easy_get_netif(true);
}

void BG96_Modem_PowerOFF(void)
{
    DigitalOut BG96_RESET(D7);
    DigitalOut BG96_PWRKEY(D10);
    DigitalOut BG97_WAKE(D11);

    BG96_RESET = 0;
    BG96_PWRKEY = 0;
    BG97_WAKE = 0;
    wait_ms(300);
}

void powerDown(){
        platform_deinit();
        BG96_Modem_PowerOFF();
}

//
// The main routine simply prints a banner, initializes the system
// starts the worker threads and waits for a termination (join)

int main(void)
{
    //printStartMessage();
    XNucleoIKS01A2 *mems_expansion_board = XNucleoIKS01A2::instance(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, D4, D5);
    hum_temp = mems_expansion_board->ht_sensor;
    acc_gyro = mems_expansion_board->acc_gyro;
    pressure = mems_expansion_board->pt_sensor;
    azure_client_thread.start(azure_task);
    azure_client_thread.join();
    platform_deinit();
    printf(" - - - - - - - ALL DONE - - - - - - - \n");
    return 0;
}

static void send_confirm_callback(IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONFIRMATION_RESULT result, void* userContextCallback)
{
    //userContextCallback;
    // When a message is sent this callback will get envoked
    g_message_count_send_confirmations++;
    deleteOK.set(0x1);
}

void sendMessage(IOTHUB_CLIENT_LL_HANDLE iotHubClientHandle, char* buffer, size_t size)
{
    IOTHUB_MESSAGE_HANDLE messageHandle = IoTHubMessage_CreateFromByteArray((const unsigned char*)buffer, size);
    if (messageHandle == NULL) {
        printf("unable to create a new IoTHubMessage\r\n");
        return;
        }
    if (IoTHubClient_LL_SendEventAsync(iotHubClientHandle, messageHandle, send_confirm_callback, NULL) != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
        printf("FAILED to send! [RSSI=%d]\n", platform_RSSI());
    else
        printf("OK. [RSSI=%d]\n",platform_RSSI());

    IoTHubMessage_Destroy(messageHandle);
}

void azure_task(void)
{
    //bool tilt_detection_enabled=true;
    float gtemp, ghumid, gpress;

    int  k;
    int  msg_sent=1;


    while (true) {
        powerUp();
        mems_init();
        /* Setup IoTHub client configuration */
        IOTHUB_CLIENT_LL_HANDLE iotHubClientHandle = IoTHubClient_LL_CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, HTTP_Protocol);

        if (iotHubClientHandle == NULL) {
            printf("Failed on IoTHubClient_Create\r\n");
            return;
            }

        // add the certificate information
        if (IoTHubClient_LL_SetOption(iotHubClientHandle, "TrustedCerts", certificates) != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
            printf("failure to set option \"TrustedCerts\"\r\n");

        #if MBED_CONF_APP_TELUSKIT == 1
            if (IoTHubClient_LL_SetOption(iotHubClientHandle, "product_info", "TELUSIOTKIT") != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
                printf("failure to set option \"product_info\"\r\n");
        #endif

        // polls will happen effectively at ~10 seconds.  The default value of minimumPollingTime is 25 minutes. 
        // For more information, see:
        //     https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/#messaging

        unsigned int minimumPollingTime = 9;
        if (IoTHubClient_LL_SetOption(iotHubClientHandle, "MinimumPollingTime", &minimumPollingTime) != IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK)
                printf("failure to set option \"MinimumPollingTime\"\r\n");

        IoTDevice* iotDev = (IoTDevice*)malloc(sizeof(IoTDevice));
        if (iotDev == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        setUpIotStruct(iotDev);

        char*  msg;
        size_t msgSize;

        hum_temp->get_temperature(&gtemp);           // get Temp
        hum_temp->get_humidity(&ghumid);             // get Humidity
        pressure->get_pressure(&gpress);             // get pressure


        iotDev->Temperature = CTOF(gtemp);
        iotDev->Humidity    = (int)ghumid;
        iotDev->Pressure    = (int)gpress;

        printf("(%04d)",msg_sent++);
        msg = makeMessage(iotDev);
        msgSize = strlen(msg);
        sendMessage(iotHubClientHandle, msg, msgSize);
        free(msg);
        iotDev->Tilt &= 0x2;

        /* schedule IoTHubClient to send events/receive commands */
        IOTHUB_CLIENT_STATUS status;
        while ((IoTHubClient_LL_GetSendStatus(iotHubClientHandle, &status) == IOTHUB_CLIENT_OK) && (status == IOTHUB_CLIENT_SEND_STATUS_BUSY))
        {
            IoTHubClient_LL_DoWork(iotHubClientHandle);
            ThisThread::sleep_for(100); 
        }
        deleteOK.wait_all(0x1);
        free(iotDev);
        IoTHubClient_LL_Destroy(iotHubClientHandle);
        powerDown();
        ThisThread::sleep_for(300000);
    }
    return;
}
```

I know PSM is probably the way to go since powering on/off the device draws a lot of power but it would be useful if someone had an idea of what is happening here.

2) putting the device to PSM between sending messages

The BG96 library in the example code I'm using doesn't have a method to turn on PSM so I tried to implement my own. When I tried to run it, it basically runs into an exception right away so I know it's wrong (I'm very new to embedded development and have no prior experience with AT commands).

```
/** ---------------------------------------------------------- 
* this is a method provided by current library
* @brief  Tx a string to the BG96 and wait for an OK response
* @param  none
* @retval true if OK received, false otherwise
*/
bool BG96::tx2bg96(char* cmd) {
    bool ok=false;
    _bg96_mutex.lock();
    ok=_parser.send(cmd) && _parser.recv("OK");
    _bg96_mutex.unlock();
    return ok;
}

/**
* method I created in an attempt to use PSM
*/
bool BG96::psm(void) {
    return tx2bg96((char*)"AT+CPSMS=1,,,”00000100”,”00000001”");
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and provide any guidance on how I can achieve my goal of having my device run on battery for longer?

Thank you!!

Comment: I cannot help much on the 2nd option but for first option do you get the same error when disconnecting and connecting network? Also what line in your .map file does your caller traces back to? Thanks.

Comment: I always get the same error, and it happens somewhere inside of IoTHubClient_LL_DoWork(iotHubClientHandle) which is after I've connected to the network (I can get IP address successfully) and before I disconnect/power down the modem. I believe the caller location is line 50123 of my .map file - it's the only place in my project folder that has "_findenv_r".

Comment: Hi ellaine, I see your issue was solved [here](https://github.com/Avnet/azure-iot-mbed-client/issues/6) . One other place I would point you to is the retry logic used by azure iot sdk for c [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/5e275b1e9f96b0001d11fad7647ba8ada62bd5d8/doc/connection_and_messaging_reliability.md#connection-establishment-and-retry-logic).

Comment: ellainec can you add the answer to this question ([same from here](https://github.com/Avnet/azure-iot-mbed-client/issues/6)) so others can benefit? Thanks!

Comment: @asergaz the answer posted on Avnet repo doesn't touch on how to put the BG96 module in PSM. I have been able to get some progress on the PSM side but the behaviour isn't what I'm expecting. Mainly, the +QPSMTIMER URC isn't reliable and I'm having trouble syncing the network active time and sending my message. I'll come back in a 2-3 weeks to either post the full answer if I've figured it out or whatever progress I've made...

Answer (score 0):

I got Power Saving Mode working by using Mbed's ATCmdParser and the AT+QPSMS commands as per Quectel's docs. The modem doesn't always go into power saving mode right away so that should be noted. I also found that I have to restart the modem afterwards or else I get weird behaviour. My code looks something like this:

```
bool BG96::psm(char* T3412, char* T3324) {
_bg96_mutex.lock();

if(_parser.send("AT+QPSMS=1,,,\"%s\",\"%s\"", T3412, T3324) && _parser.recv("OK")) {
    _bg96_mutex.unlock();
}else {
    _bg96_mutex.unlock();
    return false;
}
return BG96Ready(); }//restarts modem
```

To send a message to Azure, the modem will need to be manually woken up by driving the PWRKEY to start bi-directional communication, and a new client handle needs to be created and torn down every time since Azure connection uses keepAlive and the modem will be unreachable when it's in PSM.